# Why is Big Theta in the set Big O but not the other way around for the same function?

Tags: algorithm

I'm reading through my algorithms text and it states:

[image]

But shouldn't the vice verse be true as well, so long as the function g(n) is the same in both cases?

I understand why it wouldn't work for different functions i.e n^2 and n. But for the same function couldn't an arbitrarily smaller and larger constant be used to surround O(g(n)) to make it asymptotically tight?

Comment: You've definitely misunderstood what one of these notations means, but I can't tell which or how. :-/

Comment: @ruakh I may have, however I'm not sure. From my understanding, Big O is an upper bound, Big theta is bound between 2 contestants an upper and a lower bound. My question might be slightly confusing. I'm asking why is O(x^2) != Theta(x^2)?

Comment: 2 constants* I can't edit the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vice verse is not necessarily true since O notation establishes an upper bound for the function's complexity while Theta establishes both an upper and lower bound.

For example, for `f(x) = x²` you can say `f(x) = O(x³)` since x³ is indeed an upper bound for x² but you cannot say `f(x) = ϴ(x³)` since x³ is not a lower bound for x².

[Take a look here for the precise definitions of O and ϴ notations](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-of-algorithms-set-3asymptotic-notations/)